# How to convert Windows Font to iText.Kernel.Font.PdfFont

Tags: .net, pdf, itext

I'm using *iText.Kernel* library in .Net and I need to set font in a Paragraph from a Windows Font (got from a TextBlock).

Does anyone know how to convert Windows Font to *iText.Kernel.Font.PdfFont* ?

Thank you.

Comment: Explain "got from a TextBlock". Do you have the path to the `.ttf`, `.otf` or `.ttc` file? (Because fonts on Windows are stored as such files in the Windows Font directory, e.g. in `C:\Windows\fonts`)

Comment: @Bruno Lowagie : When I said "from a Textblock" : a TextBlock has FontSize, FontStyle, FontFamily, FontStretch and FontWeight properties. I think a font is defined by these properties, and I search to convert this properties in PdfFont. I havn't got the font path, but if I can convert these properties to find the path it can be a solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution that I found **with the help of Bruno Lowagie** :

- Before the PDF creation, register all fonts :

  ```
      PdfFontFactory.RegisterSystemDirectories()
  ```
- I stored the following textblock properties in the custom class (*ptb* named variable in my case) : FontWeight, FontStyle, FontSize, FontFamily
- I created a method to convert a System.Windows.FontWeight as Integer (value represents the PDF FontStyle) :

  ```
  Public Function ConvertWeightToPdfStyleInteger(p_originalWeight As System.Windows.FontWeight, Optional p_isItalic As Boolean = False) As Integer
  Select Case p_originalWeight
      Case Windows.FontWeights.Normal
          If p_isItalic Then
              Return 2 'ITALIC
          Else
              Return 0 'NORMAL
          End If
      Case Windows.FontWeights.Bold
          If p_isItalic Then
              Return 3 'BOLDITALIC
          Else
              Return 1 'BOLD
          End If
      Case Else
          If p_isItalic Then
              Return 2 'ITALIC
          Else
              Return -1 'UNDEFINED
          End If
  End Select
  End Function
  ```

I found the equivalent Integer values [here](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/7.1.1/constant-values.html#com.itextpdf.io.font.constants.FontStyles.BOLD)

- I called the CreateRegisteredFont() method to create the PDF font from the Windows font :

  ```
  Dim font As PdfFont = PdfFontFactory.CreateRegisteredFont(ptb.FontFamily.ToString(), PdfEncodings.IDENTITY_H, True, FontHelper.ConvertWeightToPdfStyleInteger(ptb.FontWeight, (ptb.FontStyle = Windows.FontStyles.Italic)))
  ```
- I applied the PDF font to my Paragraph :

  ```
  Dim para As Paragraph = New Paragraph(ptb.Text).SetFont(font)
  ```

And it's working find. I hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

Please take a look at the [`FontProgramFactory`](http://itextsupport.com/apidocs/iText7/7.1.1/com/itextpdf/io/font/FontProgramFactory.html).

You really need a font program (stored in a `.ttf`, `.otf`, `.ttc`,... file), but if you don't want to create a `PdfFont` by passing the path to such a file, you can register font files and font directory to the `FontProgramFactory` (e.g using the `registerFontDirectory()`, `registerFont()`, `registerFontFamily()` methods).

Once font files are registered, you can the `FontProgram` instance you need to create a `PdfFont` using methods such as `createRegisteredFont(String fontName, int style)`.

Obviously, the font size isn't a property of the font. That would be silly, because that would mean you need a different font for every different font size.

In a comment, you were also talking about CSS properties such as font-weight. You may benefit from reading the HTML to PDF tutorial, for instance the [chapter about fonts](https://developers.itextpdf.com/content/itext-7-converting-html-pdf-pdfhtml/chapter-6-using-fonts-pdfhtml).